# Is there any way to promisify node's functions and get intellisense with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, bluebird

I'm using `@types` definitions and added `@types/bluebird`, as expected I get autocomplete when using the methods from the library. However I would like to promisify node's functions (fs). I'm able to do that with the following line:

```
import * as Promise from 'bluebird'
import * as fs from 'fs'

const fsPromisified = Promise.promisifyAll(fs)
```

The problem is that when I do fsPromisified I lose autocomplete.

Is there any way I can do this without having to wrap around node's functions myself with promises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pre-promisified `mz/fs` instead of `fs`, which wraps all promisifies all async `fs` functions (with their original names, not the `Async` prefix). That package has TypeScript typings ([`@types/mz`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mz)):

```js
import * as fs from 'mz/fs';

// e.g., read file
fs.readFile('somefile')
  .then((contents) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Comment: Superb! Thanks for sharing! Any idea if node plans to add support for promises instead of callbacks?

Comment: @CésarAlberca I'm not sure if there are any specific plans, but there have been discussions about it, see [nodejs/NG#25](https://github.com/nodejs/NG/issues/25), [nodejs/node#11](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11) and [nodejs/node#4596](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4596)

Comment: @CésarAlberca Also found this working group for this topic: [nodejs/promises](https://github.com/nodejs/promises)